# How to display Content ISO 8859-15 in utf8 CKEDITOR5

Tags: encoding, utf-8, iso, ckeditor5, iso-8859-15

The content we load to ckeditor5 comes from a sql database which stores the data in iso 8859-15 encoding.
The header of the page that display the text in ckeditor have content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15;"
In this configuration, ckeditor5 does not display correctly certain characters (space ...) because `utf8 ckeditor default encoding and ISO 8859-15 (SQL Content)`.
I cannot change the encoding of SQL database and that I need to store the content in the sql base.

We use a isapi dll in IIS environment. The web service performs a data extraction from sql code. The data is stored in ISO 885915 format in the database. The result is transformed using xsl to build an HTML page.
The content is prefilled in a div when building the html page. The header of the HTML page that display the text in ckeditor have `content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15;"` We use

```
<script src="../build/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>ClassicEditor .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), { toolbar: {items: ['heading', ...
```

to configure the editor in the HTML

I need help, thanks !

Thanks

Comment: Your web application is unlikely to have direct access into the SQL database. In order to help you, you should provide more information about the entire chain of systems between browser and database. What system generates the HTTP response for the text to edit? What Javascript code is run to configure the editor? And so on... Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: We use a isapi dll in IIS environment. The web service performs a data extraction from sql code. The data is stored in ISO 885915 format in the database. The result is transformed using xsl to build an HTML page. The header of the HTML page that display the text in ckeditor have content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15;" We use  <script src="../build/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script>ClassicEditor
   .create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {  
    toolbar: {items: ['heading', ...
to configure the editor in the HTML page.

Comment: Please add this information to the question itself and not to the comments. And additionally provide information how CKEditor accesses the text: is it prefill in a *textarea* element of the HTML page, or is it fetched in a separate request? If it is a prefilled in a *textarea*, temporarily remove CKEDITOR from the page and check if it correctly appears in the *textarea*.

Comment: Ok Codo I just updated the question ;-) thanks

Comment: Thanks. Please perform the proposed test anyway, even though you are using *div* instead of *textarea*.

Comment: I dont anderstand your comment  : " ...is it prefill in a textarea element of the HTML page, or is it fetched in a separate request? ..." ckeditor v5 dont use textarea but only div !?

Comment: The question has been answered. The text to be shown in the editor is filled into the HTML page within a DIV element. So please remove the CKEditor script in order to test whether the characters will be displayed correctly if CKEditor is not involved. Please update the question with this information. Preferably, show the relevant HTML (incl. the header of the page), show the HTTP headers attributes (visible in the inspector) and show how the characters are displayed.